# HTML 5 lang attribute not working as expected

Tags: html, lang

I'm trying to create a website that supports multiple languages with the help of the HTML lang attribute. I've found this example here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p lang="fr">Ceci est un paragraphe.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I've defined german as language in my OS and tried this with different browsers, but I always see the french paragraph as well. That's what I see:

This is a paragraph.

Ceci est un paragraphe.

Answer (score 3):

The `lang` attribute specifies the language of the element’s content. Everything else is up to the user-agent resp. the webmaster.

Example uses:

- a [screen reader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) may use it to use the appropriate pronounciation
- a browser may use it to use [syllabification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabification)
- a search engine may use it to find relevant content
- a webmaster may use it to style content accordingly, e.g. using the correct [quotation marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English_usage_of_quotation_marks#Specific_language_features) for the `q` element with CSS’s `quotes`

By no means should user-agents hide content in a different language by default. Think of these examples:

- `<p lang="en">I met a nice guy there. His name was <span lang="de">Max Mustermann</span>.`
- `<p lang="en">He said to me <q lang="de">Halt! Stopp!</q>.</p>`
- `<p lang="en">The original title is <cite>Faust. Eine Tragödie.</cite>.</p>`

When content in different languages would be hidden, they would read:

> - I met a nice guy there. His name was .
> - He said to me .
> - The original title is .

It seems you want to use it to realize a multilingual page. While this is possible with JS/CSS, it’s usually not the best way. Typically you might want to use separate pages for each language and link the translation with the [link type `alternate`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-alternate) and the corresponding [`hreflang`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-hreflang):

```
<!-- on the page <example.com/en/about-me>, you could link to the German translation -->
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="/de/ueber-mich" />
```